# PreferenceActivity MultiSelectListPreference uncheck all

Tags: android, android-multiselectlistpreference

When first time I'm opening **MultiSelectListPreference** or when uncheck all check boxes and reopen **MultiSelectListPreference**, all items are displaying as checked.

I need to uncheck all check boxes on above situations.

How can I solve this?

**settings.xml**

```
   <MultiSelectListPreference
        android:entries="@array/pref_color_list_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_color_list_values"
        android:key="prefColor"
        android:summary="@string/pref_color_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_color_title" >
    </MultiSelectListPreference>
```

**strings.xml**

```
    <string-array name="pref_color_list_titles">
        <item>Red</item>
        <item>Green</item>
        <item>Blue</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="pref_color_list_values">
        <item>r</item>
        <item>g</item>
        <item>b</item>
    </string-array>
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more code, like the java code you use to display the activity and etc...?

Comment: @k3v1n4ud3 question updated.

Comment: You can add "android:defaultValue=''" and then specify the default one you want. You also might want to persist your choices using sharedPreferences.

Answer (score 2):

You need just to pass empty Set to MultiSelectListPreference

```
Set<String> uncheckValues = new HashSet<>();
myMultiSelectListPreference.setValues(uncheckValues);
```

If you want check all values, you can do this one

```
String[] defaultValuesAsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.default_values_multiselectlist_pref);
Set<String> defaultValues = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(defaultValuesAsArray)); //convert array to set
myMultiSelectListPreference.setValues(defaultValues);
```